# How to deploy a silverlight project which depends on other projects?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have created a silverlight project with dependencies to other projects within the same solution. VS has created for me an aspx page. Can  just copy and paste this web project dir only to the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just publish the web project (not the silverlight project!) to your webserver and visual studio will take care about everything else...

Answer (score 1):

ILMerge is the solution, take a look at

[ILMerge for Silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217010/ilmerge-for-silverlight-4)

and http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/leveraging-ilmerge-to-simplify-deployment-and-your-users-experience/

Comment: That wasn't exactly my question but it is very interesting thanks.